# Java MongoDB query - group, max to get child array field

Tags: java, mongodb, group-by, max

I am totally new to MongoDb. Is there a way to improve my Java query below, e.g. without sorting to get the correct document with the highest value of time for a distinct region ?

```
  Bson match = Aggregates.match(
                Filters.eq("country._id", countryId)
        );

        Bson sort = Aggregates.sort(
                Indexes.descending("time", "region._id")
        );

        Bson group = Aggregates.group(
                "region._id",
                Accumulators.max("time", "$time"),
                Accumulators.first("contentList", "$contentList")
        );

        List<Data> dataList = dataMongoCollection.aggregate(
                Arrays.asList(
                        match,
                        sort,
                        group
                )
        ).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Sample document:

```
{
   "_id":"ObjectId(""60"")",
   "contentList":[
      {
         "colors":[
            {
               "displayName":"Red",
               "reference":"red_0",
               "value":"red"
            }
         ],
         "country":{
            "_id":"countryId",
            "name":"Sweden"
         },
         "region":{
            "_id":"regionId",
            "name":"Stockholm"
         },
         "score":20002.4,
         "time":NumberLong(16237),
         "weights":[
            {
               "displayName":"Red",
               "reference":"weight_0",
               "value":0.08
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "country":{
      "_id":"c_0",
      "name":"Sweden"
   },
   "granularity":"PT15M",
   "region":{
      "_id":"r_0",
      "name":"Stockholm"
   },
   "time":NumberLong(1623751979098)
}
```

Comment: You can include a sample document you are working with in your post - so that someone can figure a way to help.

Comment: I have already attached a sample data. You cannot see it ? :)

Comment: I added to the post as a formatted document - so that its readable.

Comment: I think the _sort_ is not required. The grouping will give you distinct region and the max time for that region.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) I believe that we need the sort since first returns the first best document. I have tested it only with first without sorting. It didn't work unfortunately. And without first I only get time not contentList. Is there a way to using some other syntax instead of first to get the right document ?

Comment: Yes, you are right that sort is not needed if I only need to get maxTime for a distinct region. I need to extract the contentList (maybe I wasn't clear) Sorry about that.